# Build web package without MS Web Deploy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Is it possible to simply build a web package using only MS Build? I'm trying to build it but keeps complaining that MS Web Deploy isn't installed.

Comment: The Web Deployment Packages require Web Deploy to be installed to generate.

Comment: @jessehouwing OK fair enough, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on automating the build process for my asp.net mvc application.  **If it is an asp.net or asp.net mvc application, we need to use web deploy**.  If we run aspnet_compiler on our application it creates a precompiled output and on deploying this to iis works fine. In order to create a build artifact, we need to use web deploy.  Reply if you need more, I could help you as I did this early.